# Low Events :: How do I output the category id of an event inside the {exp:low_events:calendar} tag?

Tags: low-events

I'm using the calendar tag ( exp:low_events:calendar ...) to output a calendar from my events channel that implements the low_events fieldtype eg:

```
            {exp:low_events:calendar channel="events" date="{pre_date}" show_future_entries="yes" disable="category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"}
            <table class="calendarBG" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="My Calendar">
                <tr class="calendarHeader">
                    <th class="caption">
                        <div class="calendarMonthLinks"><a href="{path="events/{prev_month_url}"}" title="{prev_month format='%F %Y'}" class="calendar-nav">&lt;</a></div>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="5">
                        <a href="{path="events/{this_month_url}"}">{this_month format="%F %Y"}</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <div class="calendarMonthLinks"><a href="{path="events/{next_month_url}"}" title="{next_month format='%F %Y'}" class="calendar-nav">&gt;</a></div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {weekdays}<th scope="col" class="calendarDayHeading">{weekday_1}</th>{/weekdays}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {weeks}
                    <tr{if is_given_week} class="given-week"{/if}>
                        {days}
                            {if events_on_day}
                                <td class="event {if is_current}current{/if}{if is_given} given{/if}{if is_today} today{/if}">
                                <a href="{path="events/{day_url}"}">{day_number}</a>                                                      
                                </td>
                            {if:else}
                                <td class="{if is_current}current{/if}{if is_given} given{/if}{if is_today} today{/if}">
                                <span>{day_number}</span>
                                </td>
                            {/if}
                        {/days}
                    </tr>
                {/weeks}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            {/exp:low_events:calendar}
```

I'm using categories to distinguish different types of events.

I would like to add a class to the {day_number} so that diffent types of events can be styled with different background colors eg:

```
{if events_on_day}
    <a href="{path="events/{day_url}"}" class="{if category_id=='1'}yellow{/if} {if category_id=='2'} blue{/if}">{day_number}</a>
{/if}
```

​
But it doesn't look like category_id is an available variable inside the calendar tag

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

As answered via email:

I’m afraid that’s not possible. The Calendar tag doesn’t give you any info about which entries are valid for a given date, for performance reasons. Therefore, you can’t access any event/entry data in the Calendar tag. The only info there is, is how many events there are based on the parameters, that’s it.